# What is the use of SECTION variable in a recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

What is the use of SECTION variable in yocto recipe.

For example, in service_0.1.bb present in poky/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/service

```
SECTION = "base"
```

I don't think it is necessary, i wrote a simple hello world recipe and skipped the SECTION variable and there were no errors/warnings.

What are the list of values we can provide to SECTION and who uses this variable. What's the benefit of defining this variable

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at [reference manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SECTION) show that:

> The section in which packages should be categorized. Package management utilities can make use of this variable.

So as you say it's not something required, just an extra bit of information that could be used to categorize packages. It is used by the standard package classes (package_rpm.bbclass, package_deb.bbclass and package_ipk.bbclass) to populate the meta data of the packages.

Comment: @FlorianBerndl Not sure what folder structure you are referring too?